# May the elements in a std::vector have a throwing destructor?

Tags: c++, standards-compliance

When I look at the [`Container`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container) requirements on cppreference it lists [`Destructible`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Destructible) as a requirement for `value_type`. This seems to imply that destructors of container elements may not throw.

I haven't been able to find a citation for this requirement in the C++14 standard (haven't looked in older versions). The only thing I can find is that `value_type` must be [`Erasable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Erasable) which doesn't imply any exception safety at all.

So my question is, may the elements in a `std::vector` have a throwing destructor? If not, what section in the standard prohibits it?

---

P.S.: Don't worry, I'm not planning to create types with throwing destructors. I'm just writing a standard-conforming implementation and trying to get exception safety right.

Comment: Table 14 in the C++11 Standard says the same thing your cppreference says of Destructible: "no exception is propagated".

Comment: cppreference updated to agree with Table 96, sorry for rendering your question obsolete

Comment: @TonyD My question is not about Destructible, it's about `std::vector`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

N4140 [res.on.functions]/2 states:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> (2.1) — for replacement functions (18.6.1), if the installed replacement function does not implement the semantics of the applicable Required behavior: paragraph.
>
> (2.2) — for handler functions (18.6.2.3, 18.8.3.1, D.11.1), if the installed handler function does not implement the semantics of the applicable Required behavior: paragraph
>
> (2.3) — for types used as template arguments when instantiating a template component, if the operations on the type do not implement the semantics of the applicable Requirements subclause (17.6.3.5, 23.2, 24.2, 26.2). Operations on such types can report a failure by throwing an exception unless otherwise specified.
>
> (2.4) — **if any replacement function or handler function or destructor operation exits via an 
>   exception, unless specifically allowed in the applicable Required behavior: paragraph.**
>
> (2.5) — if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

Which is a bit obscure, but saves a lot of space that would otherwise be wasted on "`T` must meet the Destructible requirements" statements throughout the library clauses.

Notably, this does not imply that elements of a `std::vector` can't have a throwing destructor; it only means that said destructor must never throw when called from the standard library. So e.g. this program is conforming:

```
#include <vector>

struct A {
  bool throw_an_int = false;
  ~A() noexcept(false) {
    if (throw_an_int) throw 42;
  }
};

int main() {
  try {
    A a; 
    a.throw_an_int = true;
    std::vector<A> lots_of_As(42);
  } catch(int&) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.<sup>†</sup> The standard says this in general requirements:

<sub>`[C++11: §23.2.1/10]:`</sub>

> Unless otherwise specified (see 23.2.4.1, 23.2.5.1, 23.3.3.4, and
>   23.3.6.5) all container types defined in this Clause meet the following additional requirements:
>
> — no erase(), clear(), pop_back() or pop_front() function throws an exception.

Using the `clear` function as an example (due to it not being an exception to the general requirement) it has the following requirements:

> Destroys all elements in a. Invalidates all references, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a and may invalidate the past-the-end iterator. Post: `a.empty()` returns `true`

Which means that it essentially calls the `std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::destroy` on all elements. Which delegates over to `t->~T()` if `a.destroy(t)` is unavailable. However this implicitly guarantees that neither `a.destroy(t)` nor `t->~T()` should throw because it'll violate `clear`'s strong `noexcept` specification:

```
// § 23.3.6.1
void clear() noexcept;
```

So through deduction we could assert that destructors can throw but they have to be suppressed through some mechanism such as wrapping them in a try-catch block.

†: Upon further inspection, it seems that destructors *can* throw but the exceptions have to be suppressed as stated in the comments below.

Comment: But that doesn't prohibit `void clear() noexcept { try { _ActualClear(); } catch(...) { } }` implementation, does it?

Comment: Like @Joker_vD says, `noexcept` isn't a guarantee that no execution of a function can result in an exception being thrown, it's a guarantee that no exceptions will be emitted from that function.

Comment: So a custom allocator could provide an exception-suppressing `destroy`, allowing `value_type` to have a throwing destructor.. shouldn't your first line then say "Yes"?

Comment: I had accepted your answer Rapptz, but after reading everything again I actually think Casey has got it right. Yes, destructors may throw, however no effects are defined if it happens unless specifically said otherwise.